# How to call a php function from a submit having the value of the input?

Tags: php, post, input, submit

I'm encountering a small problem. I would like, when I press my button, to create a database, I name it as I want using my text input. I'd like to do this in php. If anyone can help me I would be very grateful

**index.php :**

```
require("secret.php");
require("getDatabases.php");

$conn = new PDO($servername, $username, $password);
$databases = getDatabases($conn);
// $createDB = create_db($conn, $name);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>phpMyAdmin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- list databases-->
    <div class="list-group">
        <?php
            foreach($databases as $data){
                echo "<button type=button class=list-group-item list-group-item-action>". htmlspecialchars($data)."</button>";
            }   
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- to create database -->
    <form method="post" action="./database/createDB.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Create your database"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create my DB">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**createDB.php :**

```
function createDB($pdo, $name)
{
    $create = `CREATE DATABASE $name`;
    $pdo->exec($create);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   createDB();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add a `name` attribute to your form input text field, and then retrieve that in your main code in `createDB.php`. Then you'll need to pass that name (after validation), and your `$pdo` database connection object, into the `createDB()` function, as it requires those two parameters.

Comment: Adding on to what @droopsnoot said, you'll also want to filter your inputs and use prepared statements

Comment: it's possible to have a demonstration ? :)

Comment: You can already see how to look at form variables, because you do that to check whether the form was submitted. It should be clear then how to extract the name from the form variables, and add it as a parameter. Not sure where you'll get your `$pdo` variable from - often that's created in an include file, but you seem to do it manually in your code. So copy the code that connects to your database server.